# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname when accessing localhost using IP address

Tags: visual-studio, iis, ip, iis-express

I'm using Visual Studio and IIS Express to run a web app locally.
I can access the web app without any issues using `https://localhost:44300`.

Out of curiosity, I wanted to access it using the IP address, so I tried `https://10.1.1.229:44300` but am getting this error:

[image]

I thought I could replace localhost with my private IP address which I got from `ipconfig`:
[image]

I also noticed it says the certificate is not secure.

How can I access my local web app using the IP address?

Comment: That's not a surprise. By default, VS only generates a site on IIS Express and bind to `localhost`, so you cannot use IP address. That's how IIS site bindings work, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Modifying the bindings is not recommended as you are only debugging locally. To test a site with production settings, publish to full IIS and manage the settings there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following settings to `~\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config' file`.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="ip address:port:host header" />
```